# Не применяются стили для класса имеющего paintEvent()

Tags: c++, qt

Пытаюсь добавить стили для моего класса с помощью **setStyleSheet()** но они не применяются. Как только закомментирую метод **paintEvent()** стили применяются.
Сам класс унаследован от **QWidget** и имеет **Q_OBJECT**

Comment: Стандартный пример у вас работает https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_Style_Sheets_and_Custom_Painting_Example  ? Тогда, приведите свой пример кода, который не работает.

Comment: Этот пример не работает. Вот мой код: https://codeshare.io/ezV9M4